# Product & technique recommendation to trim this door

Tags: outdoor, exterior, trim, door-frame

So I had a new retaining wall built for the walkout from my basement, and there is a small gap (about an inch) between between the door frame and the wall. Currently it is filled with spray foam that's about 20 years old.

Quite clearly this looks crap, and is a poor choice for winter proofing. My current plan is to remove the old spray foam and replace with fresh product, then apply a veneer of mortar between the wall and doorframe. Also thinking about putting some basic white trim over the exposed section.

So my question is, if this was your house what product(s) would you use and how would you trim the door? I'm in Ontario, Canada.

[image: Door]

Comment: Sorry to make bad worse, but why would you create a retaining wall to the point where the door won't fully open?

Comment: This requires a custom fit. I think that you could buy whatever frame you thought looked good, or that will still look okay after cutting it to fit.

Comment: Don't mortar against the jamb. That will accomplish nothing with respect to weather-proofing, and will likely crumble away due to movement. Use low-expansion foam, then trim with vinyl as Jack suggests. I'd even caulk the trim in place with urethane (by far the best product I've used for this purpose).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purchase a 1" thick by 3 1/2" wide PVC trim to go around the 3 sides of the door. Ripping to width were it fit to a proper set back from the edge of the jamb in all areas below the masonry cap of the walls. In essence, trimming in out in a typical fashion the way interior doors are trimmed.

A thinner trim would work but the thicker trim allows the back side that meets the rough wall to be cut out so it goes over the irregular surface. With care the edge that will meet the door jam will remain full thickness, keeping that joint looking as clean as allowable, provided the conditions you are working with.

I would use PVC over the choice of wood since it is impervious to rot.

Comment: It will be a hell of an odd cut to get a long piece of trim to fit.  Probably better off with some stones here.

Comment: I agree with Jack on everything except PVC trim. with areas that experience large temp swings PVC cracks.  Cedar "brick mold" is an exterior trim made for just this type of case and it will last.

Comment: I've never seen PVC crack, and I'm in about the swingingest climate there is. Maybe we're talking about two different products? I have in mind extruded, solid-core moldings.

Comment: I am referring to a solid PVC material, that is for all intents the same as 5/4X4" in wood. Since it is all going either beside masonry, (at the retainer walls) or over a good portion of masonry around the door, (the foundation walls), using wood would degrade soon enough, (cedar too, seen it). It could be backprimed which may help it last 10-20 years, and maybe that is all that is needed since the door will be on its' way out by that time too. PVC will never have an issue. It is available in brick mold pattern, but 2" wide material will not cover the trouble on the upper right side.